# PostMan: HTTPS Get request/ The underlying connection was closed: could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net, ssl, mule, postman

I am making HTTPS get request through PostMan I am getting the following error message :
The underlying connection was closed: could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
is there any specific setting should I do it in PostMan (like adding on the request ) ?

BTW: the Url I am calling  is based on Mulesoft

Comment: As it is get request, did you tried on chrome or explorer, so you would understand if it is a SSL certificate issue with postman

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following; however, it's not recommended:

Postman >> Preferences >> SSL certificate verification OFF

Handling certs properly:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates

Overall explanation of settings:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/settings